# Can I use CSS pseudo elements to wrap some text in brackets?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Can I use CSS pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` to wrap some text in brackets?

i.e.

```
Text
```

becomes:

```
(Text)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can

http://jsfiddle.net/GHL6u/

```
<span>text</span>

span:before {
    content: '(';
}

span:after {
    content: ')';
}
```